# NSSortDescriptor using the minimum value of a date in a related object

Tags: ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have a Core Data entity, `MediaAsset`. I have another called `UploadAttempt` which tracks all of the attempts we've made to upload that `MediaAsset` to our central server. I would like to fetch `MediaAsset`s from the datastore ordered by the first `UploadAttempt`.

`MediaAsset` has 3 `UploadAttempt`s, A, B, and C. `UploadAttempt` has an attemptDate attribute and I would like to find the earliest UploadAttempt for each MediaAsset and use that as the sorting.

I would like to create an NSSortDescriptor something along the lines of:

`order by MediaAsset.uploadAttempts.attemptDate` where attemptDate is the earliest attemptDate for that particular MediaAsset.

Does that make sense? Any help is appreciated.

(note: assume I cannot add an additional attribute to the MediaAsset. This is already existing data and I can't alter it.)

Comment: You mean to say- MediaAsset and UploadAttempt are 2 separate entities? In such a case, are they tied via a 1-1 relationship?

Comment: 1-to-many. Each MediaAsset may have multiple UploadAttempts.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should work. If not, please ping me again, we will understand and correct it together.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UploadAttempt" 
 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDesc];
NSError *error = nil;


NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" 
ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];    

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSArray *dateSortedAttempts = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest  
error:&error];

NSSet* mediaAssets= [NSSet setWithArray:[items valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.MediaAsset"]];
```

Comment: That looks very interesting, I didn't know about that set function, but won't I lose the ordering of the MediaAssets when they are turned into an NSSet since a set is an unordered collection?

Comment: That's true. I agree- missed that point. Could you read through the various operators in KVC Guide in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html. There are stuff you can do like arrays, too.